# how to do a HTTP POST a list of value using cURL

Tags: http, post, curl

how I do post multiple values to the same key using cURL?

for example when I ran the following to my example.com URL, it complained...is the format correct or is this a problem with the backend not being able to handle the request?

```
curl -k -H 'Accept: application/json' --user admin:admin example.com -d name=peter -d name=paul -d name=mary
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple `-d` looks fine. The docs said `-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy` will generate `name=daniel&skill=lousy`

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d

So if you want send an array, you have to use the `[]` brackets.

```
-d name[]=peter -d name[]=paul -d name[]=mary
```

It looks like you can also use

```
-d "name[]=peter&name[]=paul&name=mary"
```

Comment: Thanks for the information...however, my origin question was how to post multiple values to the same key in cURL

Comment: Oh sorry. I forgot this while writing. Now the answer is up to date.