# Flask-Restful: Passing list into MongoDB via POST request

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, command-line-interface, flask-restful

I'm building an API for a new web service using Python, Flask-Restful w/ pymongo.

A sample MongoDB document **should** look like this:

```
{ domain: 'foobar.com',
  attributes: { web: [ akamai,
                       google-analytics,
                       drupal,
                       ... ] } }
```

**The imports:**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask.ext.restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
from pymongo import MongoClient
```

**The class:**

```
class AttributesAPI(Resource):
def __init__(self):
    self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
    self.reqparse.add_argument('domain', type = str, required = True, help = 'No domain given', location='json')
    self.reqparse.add_argument('web', type = str, action='append', required = True, help = 'No array/list of web stuff given', location = 'json')
    super(AttributesAPI, self).__init__()

def post(self):
    args = self.reqparse.parse_args()
    post = db.core.update(  {'domain': args['domain']},
                            {'$set':{'attr': {  'web': args['web'] }}},
                            upsert=True)
    return post
```

**When I CURL post, I use this:**

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"domain":"foobar", "web":"akamai", "web":"drupal", "web":"google-analytics"}' http://localhost:5000/v1/attributes
```

**However, this is what gets saved in my document:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5313a9006759a3e0af4e548a"), "attr" : { "web" : [  "google-analytics" ] }, "domain" : "foobar.com"}
```

It only stores the last value given in the curl for 'web'. I also tried to use the CLI command with multiple -d params as described in the [reqparse documentation](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reqparse.html#basic-arguments) but that throws a 400 - BAD REQUEST error.

Any ideas how why it is only saving the last value instead of all values as a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON objects and in Python dictionaries, names are *unique*; you cannot repeat the `web` key here and expect it to work. Use *one* `web` key instead and make the value a list:

```
{"domain": "foobar", "web": ["akamai", "drupal", "google-analytics"]}
```

and it should be processed as such.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Martijn. I'm having issues passing in the values as list for the web key via CURL without flask-restful throwing me a 400 - Bad Request error. How would you write the CURL command so that it's one list? I also tried the answers [from this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368316/how-to-do-a-http-post-a-list-of-value-using-curl") but that's throwing a 400 - Bad Request when I use it as CURL command.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Martin Pieters answer, you would need to set your `location` parameter on your `self.reqparse.add_argument` to a tuple of `json` and `values` and the `store` parameter is `append`

```
self.reqparse.add_argument('domain',store='append', type = str, required = True, help = 'No domain given', location=('json','values'))
`
```